# Devise validation for sign in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When I go to devise sign page, It is not showing any validation alert message, like if I enter wrong email id or password or even if I leave it blank it just reloads the page without showing any error messages. What should I do to show validation messages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you have to take care for it yourself to display the flash[:notice] and the flash[:alert] messages. The usual place to do that is the layout file in which your devise views are rendered in. At the moment either you only render flash[:notice] thus the failing login messages isn't displayed as it is a flash[:alert] message or you don't display your flash messages at all.

Some links concerning the same problem:

1. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/plataformatec-devise/ZAyn3W7cVAg
2. [Devise flash messages don't show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948178/devise-flash-messages-dont-show-up)

You can change the layouts the devise views use in your application.rb, e.g.:

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.layout "session"
  Devise::PasswordsController.layout "application"
end
```

Comment: but how do I generate controller for devise ?

Comment: You don't need to generate a controller, only configure the layout file the devise views should use. See my updated answer.